# Cannot find rails.cmd or rails.bat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-in-steel

I installed ruby in steel (visual studio8) on windows 7 ultimate. But when i create a rail application the following error message is displayed:

Cannot find rails.cmd or rails.bat (looked in C:\Ruby\Bin); Rails may not be installed - continue?

Please tell me how to fix this issue???

Comment: "Rails may not be installed" -- well, is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Tutorials/Ruby-In-Steel-Tutorials/Hints-Tips-and-Installation/Setting-Up-Ruby-and-Rails-For-Ruby

Here's the install docs. It sounds like either you haven't run "gem install rails" or your paths are wrong.

Comment: @pushcx This URL not longer work. It showing me 404 error.